# Excel merge add data to sheet1 from sheet2

Tags: excel

I have two sheets.
The `first` one is complete `list` of `users` with their `ids`, `names` and `emails`:

```
+------+----------+----------------------+
|  ID  |   Name   |        Email         |
+------+----------+----------------------+
| 1234 | Stephen  | stephen@example.com  |
| 1434 | Mark     | Mark@example.com     |
| 1244 | Beatrice | Beatrice@example.com |
| 123* | Claudia  | Claudia@example.com  |
| 1278 | Juno     | Juno@example.com     |
| 1293 | Albert   | Albert@example.com   |
| 1264 | Key      | Key@example.com      |
+------+----------+----------------------+
```

In the `second` sheet they are the `ids`, `names`, `cars` of the users like this:

```
+------+----------+-------------+
|  ID  |   Name   |    Cars     |
+------+----------+-------------+
| 1434 | Mark     | Opel        |
| 1434 | Mark     | BMW         |
| 1278 | Juno     | Nissan      |
| 1244 | Beatrice | Mercedes    |
| 123* | Claudia  | Renault     |
| 1234 | Stephen  | AstonMartin |
| 1278 | Juno     | Citroen     |
| 1293 | Albert   | Dacia       |
| 1244 | Beatrice | Dacia       |
| 1264 | Key      | Lancia      |
| 1434 | Mark     | Lancia      |
+------+----------+-------------+
```

How to `add` to each `line` with `ID` in the second sheet the users `email` according to each line of data for the user?

Comment: The function you're looking for is [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).  Give it a try and if you run into problems, please post back what you tried.

Comment: I tried `=VLOOKUP(A2Sheet1!$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSCH)` sorry for the German. But it won't show me anything

Comment: You would want: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$8,3,FALSCH)`